# How to embed images from Google Drive to SSRS but images is in private mode (need authentication to access this images)?

Tags: reporting-services, google-drive-api

I'm trying to embed images from Google Drive to SSRS but images is in private mode (need authentication to access this images). I already sucessfully embed images from Google Drive if images in public mode, but because we need to keep priviledge so we need to change permission in private mode or just using authentication for accessing the images.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to read pictures from your Drive on a private server running SSRS. If my understanding is correct, then you can accomplish your goal easily. You will need to set up server side credentials as detailed by [these](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#prerequisites) steps. Later, you have to include those credentials in your server and link them to your code. Please, ask me any question if you still have doubts.